# parsedatetime to show a data range?

Tags: python, datetime

Am I missing something, or does parsedatetime not do date ranges like so:

`"Next January"` - ideally should return something like `('Jan 1st 2012', 'Jan 31st 2012')`

(sudo code - obviously proper python date objects)

Similarly,

`"Tomorrow"` might return something like `('Dec 23rd 2011 00:00', 'Dec 23rd 2011 23.59')`

I see it can parse things like `"Aug 24th - Sept 1st 2012"` as a range - I wondered if it could do single phrase dates and work that out?

Or if it could tell me what date/time period it found - i.e. `month` for the first example, `day` for the second.

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code I see a few regular expressions that pretty much explain what kind of ranges can be parsed (I've removed some lines that deal with locales):

```
# "06/07/06 - 08/09/06"
self.DATERNG1 = self.RE_RDATE + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RDATE

# "march 31 - june 1st, 2006"
self.DATERNG2 = self.RE_RDATE3 + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RDATE3

# "march 1rd -13th"
self.DATERNG3 = self.RE_RDATE3 + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?(\d\d?)\s?(rd|st|nd|th)?'

# "4:00:55 pm - 5:90:44 am", '4p-5p'
self.TIMERNG1 = self.RE_RTIMEHMS2 + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RTIMEHMS2

# "4:00 - 5:90 ", "4:55:55-3:44:55"
self.TIMERNG2 = self.RE_RTIMEHMS + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RTIMEHMS

# "4-5pm "
self.TIMERNG3 = r'\d\d?\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RTIMEHMS2

# "4:30-5pm "
self.TIMERNG4 = self.RE_RTIMEHMS + r'\s?%(rangeseperator)s\s?' + self.RE_RTIMEHMS2
```

As you can see, there is a separator used in all regular expressions to decide where to split the string and then parse start and end date.

Hence, as an answer to your question, it's not currently possible to parse single phrase as a range with the current implementation.

Comment: jcollado is correct and his answer should be flagged as answering your question.  I wrote parsedatetime's range code to only handle explicit date ranges and not to handle ranges that are implied by month, year and/or week combinations